# Facing issue with Dropbox API after migrating spring boot version to 3.2.2

Tags: spring-boot, dropbox-api, jakarta-migration, java-21, hellosign-api

We have recently upgraded spring boot version from **2.7.0** to **3.2.2** and Java version to **21**
But after upgrading the spring version, the Dropbox API has started failing on fetching Client details at

```
ApiClient apiClient = Configuration.getDefaultApiClient();
```

Error

```
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/ws/rs/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec/2.0.1.Final/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class to jar:file:/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/ws/rs/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec/2.0.1.Final/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class
```

Below are the maven dependencies for jaxrs and dropbox

```
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
                <version>3.15.6.FINAL</version>
            </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.dropbox.sign</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropbox-sign</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Currently we are not able to resolve this issue, though we have tried with different version of dropbox and jaxrs.

We would be really grateful if someone can help us in right direction here.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no version of Dropbox Sign that's compatible with Spring Boot 3. At this time, Dropbox Sign only supports Jakarta EE 8 and Spring Boot 3.x requires EE 9 or later. You'll have to use Spring Boot 2.7.x if you want to use Dropbox Sign with it.

Comment: I think you are right, either we find some other document sign library compatible with this version or downgrade the spring boot one. Thank you

Answer (score -3):

Change the version of Spring boot 3.2.2 to 3.0.0

Comment: Still facing the same issue, even if we change the spring boot version to 3.0.0